# Using multiple AND and OR statements in QUERY function - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google spreadsheet with a tab called 'Updates'. In a separate tab, I want to use drop-down menus (contained in cells B3, B4 and B5 in the code below) to filter and subsequently view the data in the 'Updates' tab according to its text in columns B, C and D.

I have written the following code. Basically I want to be able to filter the data according to selections made in all 3 drop down menus (B3, B4 and B5), or just in two of them (e.g. B3 and B4, but B5 is left blank), or just in one of them (e.g. B3, and B4 and B5 are left blank).

=query(Updates!A1:E, " select * (where B = '"&B3&"' AND C = '"&B4&"' AND D = '"&B5&"') OR (where B = '"&B3&"' OR C = '"&B4&"' OR D = '"&B5&"') OR (where (B = '"&B3&"' OR C = '"&B4&"') AND D = '"&B5&"') OR (where B = '"&B3&"' AND (C = '"&B4&"' OR D = '"&B5&"') ) OR (where C = '"&B4&"' AND (B = '"&B3&"' OR D = '"&B5&"') ")

The AND and OR functions work separately in their own query functions, but when I combine them together I get the following error message:

Error
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " "(" "( "" at line 1, column 11. Was expecting one of:  "where" ... "group" ... "pivot" ... "order" ... "skipping" ... "limit" ... "offset" ... "label" ... "format" ... "options" ...

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can use `where` only once in one `QUERY`. try:

```
=QUERY(Updates!A1:E, 
 "where 9=9 "&
 IF(B3="",," and B = '"&B3&"'")& 
 IF(B4="",," and C = '"&B4&"'")& 
 IF(B5="",," and D = '"&B5&"'"), )
```